# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I have a view controller with a UITableView. I have both the datasource and delegate set to the view controller. The method cellForRowAtIndexPath: is being called and behaving as expected however didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not being called. Any ideas whats going on here?

I have this in my .h:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

And in my viewDidLoad in the .m I have:

```
self.tableView.dataSource=self;
self.tableView.delegate=self;
```

It doesn't seem to make sense that the cellForRowAtIndexPath would be called but not didSelectRowAtIndexPath.This is what the method looks like for now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"did select row at index path");
}
```

Comment: i assume tableview is an outlet. Did you connect the delegate to view controller in storyboard ?

Comment: Is tableView.allowsSelection =YES;?

Comment: post your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and also make sure that `userInteractionEnabled = YES` and `allowsSelection = YES`

Comment: Just added both of those to viewDidLoad. Still isn't working.

Comment: add them to the bottom of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I commonly have some cells that I do not want users to click mixed in with cells I do want users to be able to click, so that is where I set it.  Maybe you accidentally have it set to NO somewhere in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Tried that too. My cellForRowAtIndexPath just sets a label so I'm not changing much in it.

Comment: Might you have a transparent view on top of your tableView that's preventing touches from reaching your tableView?

Comment: Not sure if you actually copied-and-pasted code or not, but if you didn't, double-check that when you used auto-completion, you actually chose the "did select" and not the "did deselect" method.

Comment: Also, if you use custom cells, make sure you don't have a custom setSelected/selected pair which does not actually keep state.

Comment: Did you add `UIGestureRecognizer` to your view? it can conflict with your table view's touch if you don't handle it.

Comment: Good catch. I do have a gesture recognizer in my view did load method. How can I get around this?

Comment: Figured out a way for everything to work without the UIGestureRecognizer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered some possible reasons:

1. Make sure the the editing property of tableView is set to NO. The **didSelectRowAtIndex: method** isn't called when the editing property of table is set to YES. By default this property is set to NO.

   ```
   self.tableView.editing = NO;
   ```
2. Make sure the allowsSelection property is set to YES. By default it is.
3. Try to call.**[super viewDidLoad]** in the viewDidLoad method or setting the delegate and the dataSource properties in the init initializer.
4. Set the delegate and the dataSource properties in the **loadView** method and assign the tableView to the view property of the UIViewController. Here's an example:

   ```
   - (void)loadView
   {

   UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];

   tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

   tableView.delegate = self;

   tableView.dataSource = self;

   [tableView reloadData];

   self.view = tableView;

   }
   ```
5. **(this is, actually, what I usually do)** Try to subclass DetailViewController from UITableViewController which inherits from UIViewController too. UITableViewController comforms automatically to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 4):

Gesture recognizer on a view controller's view prevented touches, solved by setting gesture recognizer's `cancelsTouchesInView` to false.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used UITapGestureRecognizer and it worked like a magic for me.

```
cell.tag=indexPath.row; 
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnCell:)]; 
[cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Here is my tapOnCell method implementation

```
-(void)tapOnCell:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
   ADPointCashTransaction* aTransaction=[transactionArray objectAtIndex:tap.view.tag];
    // Work with aTransaction Object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the answer in the comments of seto nugroho with my work around the problem. If you have a gesture recognizer in the tableView, then the didSelect row will not be called. What you can do is increase the number of taps for the gesture recognizer to two.

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add one more: make sure you don't have any other views overlapping the table or cells at any point, even hidden ones. If you do, disable 'User interaction enabled' in storyboard unless you explicitly need to catch gestures through the view.

Comment: I think disabling User interactions on a view will still cancel the taps for underlying views

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was assigning the dataSource and calling reloadData() all in a background thread. So, make sure you are doing this on the main thread.